# multiple select angular nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I need to build a multiple item select UI element for my nativescript angular app. There does not seem to be a nativescript UI component supporting multiple selection. Any examples of how I could implement this for my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Nativescript UI. List view and side drawer is free.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/selection

**multiple selection** - allows for selecting multiple items. RadListView keeps track of which items are selected and exposes them through a getSelectedItems() method. Multiple selection is enabled by setting the multipleSelection property to true.

```
<RadListView [items]="dataItems" selectionBehavior="Press" multipleSelection="true">
    <!-- << angular-listview-item-selection-multiple -->
        <template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <StackLayout class="listItemStackLayout">
                <Label class="nameLabel" [text]="item.name"></Label>
                <Label class="descriptionLabel" [text]="item.description"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
        <ListViewLinearLayout tkListViewLayout itemHeight="50" scrollDirection="Vertical"></ListViewLinearLayout>
</RadListView>
```

Along with UI trial download, There is a demo sample. Play with that.

Comment: Thanks the component does the job!