# Attaching Data To View NativeScript NG2

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

** UPDATE **

In my code I have a card which holds the current index of the job array in the view. This way a user can use a gesture to swipe the card off the screen which will then show the next index in the job array.

In my component I have

```
@ViewChild("card") card: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("job") job: ElementRef;

let jobsArray = ["Developer","Food Editor","Journalist","Actor","Fisherman","Chef","Designer","Musician","Baker"];

this.job.nativeElement = jobsArray[i];
```

That way I have the objects setup so inside this function handles when the card is swiped,

```
this.card.nativeElement.on(GestureTypes.swipe, function (args) {
 // DO stuff
}
```

My question is,

I have not been able to get any data form the job array to appear in the view. I am trying to use what I can find online to make this work but I am not sure if I am even on the right track or not.

Am I correct by using

```
@ViewChild("card") card: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("job") job: ElementRef;
```

** END UPDATE **

**Background**

I am trying to learn to write NativeScript. I have experience with Angular2 so I figured it would be simple enough.

I found an example of how to swipe through an array from the view but it was in core NativeScript.

I am trying to convert it to Angular but I am pretty sure I am not binding the data correctly.

**Example**

In the view,

```
<ActionBar title="Stream" class="action-bar">
    <ActionItem text="Menu" ios.position="left"></ActionItem>
    <ActionItem text="Group" ios.position="right"></ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" class="stream">
    <StackLayout id="card" class="card">
        <Label id="job"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

So I realized in that example that it is not how I would typically add data to an Angular2 view. So I tried this variation of adding data,

```
 <StackLayout card="card" i="index"  #card [card]="card" id="card" class="card">
```

In the component the example was originally using,

```
 var verdict = _page.getViewById("verdict");
```

But I have read when using angular2 inside nativescript you would do that like this,

```
@ViewChild("job") job: ElementRef;

let jobsArray = ["Developer","Food Editor","Journalist","Actor","Fisherman","Chef","Designer","Musician","Baker"];

this.job.nativeElement = jobsArray[i];
```

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is have a card section in my view. Then showing one index of the jobs array in the card at a time. So when I swipe the view it will move through the job array each time I swipe a card off the view.

Here is the component as I have it now,

```
export class StreamComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("card") card: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("job") job: ElementRef;

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.singleCard();
    }

    singleCard() {

        let jobsArray = ["Developer","Food Editor","Journalist","Actor","Fisherman","Chef","Designer","Musician","Baker"];

        let i = 0;

        this.card.nativeElement.on(GestureTypes.swipe, function (args) {
            this.job.nativeElement = jobsArray[i];
            i = i + 1;

            if(args.direction === 1){
                console.log("You liked it, save to your favs!")
                this.card.animate({ translate: { x: 1000, y: 100 } })
                    .then(function () { return this.card.animate({ translate: { x: 0, y: -2000 } }); })
                    .then(function () { return this.card.animate({ translate: { x: 0, y: 0 } }); })
                    .then(function () {
                        this.job.text = jobsArray[i];
                    })
                    .catch(function (e) {
                        console.log(e.message);
                    });
            }
            else{
                console.log("You hate it, get rid of that shit!")
                this.card.animate({ translate: { x: -1000, y: 100 } })
                    .then(function () { return this.card.animate({ translate: { x: 0, y: -2000 } }); })
                    .then(function () { return this.card.animate({ translate: { x: 0, y: 0 } }); })
                    .then(function () {
                        this.job.text=jobsArray[i];

                    })
                    .catch(function (e) {
                        console.log(e.message);
                    });
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**Problems**

Binding data to the view with

this.job.nativeElement

Showing the data in the view one card at a time.

Comment: Do you need to implement some thing like lazy fetch?

Comment: I am not familear with lazy fetch. What is that? Basically I am trying to get a card to hold a single index from the job array. Then when the user swipes the screen or the card it will change to the next index in the job array. My problem is attaching the data inside the card then getting the card to show up in the view. I am confused between what is core nativescript and what is used in angular. I know ng-2 but first time using nativescript. This is what I am trying to do, but this is in core nativescript. http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/snippets/2016/06/07/swipable-cards.html

Comment: I most of the cases you can use angular2 directives like ngif..
But major difference is mobile view. I believe for your case you should use listview. With some options. I will post the code.

Comment: You are amazing thank you. Your example will help a ton!

Comment: `<ListViewLinearLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Horizontal" itemWidth="80"></ListViewLinearLayout>` See the answer to use list view . But you need to change the scroll direction Anything you can implement inside `tkListItemTemplate `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731622/multiple-select-angular-nativescript/42745082#42745082

Comment: I do not think you are understanding what I am trying to do. I am trying to show data from an array inside a element in the view. SO I can make the data change with a gesture. Please see my updated section of my question. The code for the gesture works fine. I just need to get the data to appear in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example below. Create new project `tns create cardswipe --ng`
edit items.component.ts and .html
.ts

`import { SwipeGestureEventData } from "ui/gestures";`

```
items: Item[];
item: Item;
index: number = 0;

constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.itemService.getItems();
    this.item = this.items[this.index];
    this.index++;
}

onSwipe(args: SwipeGestureEventData) {

    if (this.index < this.items.length)
        this.index++;
    else
        this.index = 0;
    this.item = this.items[this.index];
}
```

html code

```
<ActionBar title="My App" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout class="page">
   <StackLayout id="card" class="card" (swipe)="onSwipe($event)">
        <Image id="guy"></Image>
        <Label id="name" [text]="item.name"></Label>
        <Label id="job" [text]="item.role"></Label>
        <Label id="age" [text]="item.id"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Add animation while swiping if needed.

app.css

```
.card{
margin:20px;
background-color:#03A9F4;
border-radius:5;
height:200px;
}

Label{
    font:40;
    color:white;
}
```